# Can slices reference difference arrays/slices in different index ranges, or is there a convenient workaround?

Tags: arrays, go, indexing, slice

Something like this

```
slice := make([]byte, 5)
slice[0:2] = someArray[3:5]  // I don't want to copy someArray[3:5], I want slice[0:2] to reference it
slice[2:5] = someArray[0:3]  // similarly, I want slice[2:5] to reference someArray[0:3]
```

Of course the above code doesn't produce the desired results, it's just to get my requirements across.

Comment: A slice represents an array, and an array is a contiguous block of memory, so no.

Answer (score 2):

No, go slices cannot do this. A slice is simply three values: the underlying array, capacity, and length. It is a simple view of the underlying array.

You can have two slices using the same underlying array, though.

```
slicea:=someArray[3:5]
sliceb:=someArray[0:3]
```

`slicea` has length=2, `sliceb` has length=3, and they are disjoint views on the same array.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a way to treat slices like circular buffers or to have some sort of workaround. I imagine there's third party libraries that would give circular buffer capabilities, but I'm not sure they'd be convenient for use with file reading.

Comment: @LostCrotchet: a circular buffer is less complicated than a general "slice view of multiple backing arrays". In fact, it's just a two-slice view of a single backing array ... but it's always two slices (one of which may be empty, and neither of which ever overlap).